# How to get the response object java

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, response, response.write

My web side I am using Jsp and jQuery and my server side I am using Java with struts2. At my Java side I want to send data after my Ajax post. I want to write something like this:

```
response.getWriter().write(value);
```

However how can I get the response object on my controller? It doesn't recognize "response" symbol. I think I should import something and set the response value? What to do from the beginning?
Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement your controller with ServletResponseAware and you can get access to response object.

Comment: When I implement it says that I should write setServletResponse(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) method but what to do for that?

Comment: That's the abstract method you should implement and assign the response to a variable in the controller. You can later use it to write the response. This method will be called by the framework and set the response object.

Comment: Should I use an interceptor for it? I didn't use any interceptor for my project yet. However I tried your solution and could write that response. My second question is: <dependency> <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId> <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId> <version>2.5</version> </dependency> this dependency is true or not for my purpose?

Comment: This dependency is generally required as provided scope, as generally all the servlet containers provides at runtime.

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, accept it by checking the green check next to answer. This will help others identify the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways of doing this are described in [the struts faq](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/how-can-we-access-the-httpservletresponse.html).  The second and likely preferred way is the one suggested by Teja Kantamneni, whose response I'm upvoting.

Comment: I have added that dependency to my code also:    
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
I think that's the correct dependency for that aim?